# SparkJava "Secure" method will not work for me, at all

Tags: spark-java

I'm totally unable to get the 'secure' method to work in my SparkJava web service.

I have the "secure" command correctly defined at the top of the "App.java" class. It correctly references the full path to the keystore.jks file (which works fine with Tomcat) and has the correct password.

Yet when I try to start the service from, say, the Desktop (which correctly works without the "secure" command), I get a Java IO Exception that makes no sense: "/Users/Test/Desktop is a directory"

The full path to the keystore file, specified in the "secure" command is different. That path is: /Users/Test/Keystores/keystore.jks

Here's the full error stack sparkJava returns:

```
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.PathResource.getInputStream(PathResource.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(CertificateUtils.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadTrustStore(SslContextFactory.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.load(SslContextFactory.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.doStart(SslConnectionFactory.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer.ignite(EmbeddedJettyServer.java:130)
    at spark.Service.lambda$init$2(Service.java:504)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

---

If anyone has been able to get this command to work, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

---

Code example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //------------------------
        // This code does not work
        // Despite the fact that
        // the Keystore works
        // correctly with Tomcat.
        //------------------------
        String keyStoreLocation =    "/<Path_to_keystore_file>/keystore.jks";
        String keyStorePassword = "password";
        secure(keyStoreLocation, keyStorePassword, "", "");
        .
        .
        .
        // other methods...

    }
```

Comment: If you could post some code...

Comment: Added code above. Thanks. If you have working secure code from SparkJava, I'd like to understand how it differs from the code sample above.

Comment: Could you replace the empty strings with `null`? In our production code we use `null`s

Comment: Yes!!! This worked!!! Putting "null" for my empty quoted strings fixed the problem.

THANK YOU!!!! :)

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: Can't tell you how frustrating that error was. If the "null" was in the documentation, I apologize as I missed it. Your response was perfect and totally solved the problem. :)